# Laravel 5.2 use two different database connections simultaneously (sqlsrv + mysql)

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5, sqlsrv

I would like to do something like this when i use a model

```
class DB extends Model {

Protected $table = "mssql_table";
}

DB::useConnection("mssql")->All();
```

As far as configuration goes i've found out that I can add it myself in app/config/database.php

And so I did.

So now i've got this in my connetions:

```
'mssql' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => env('DB_MSSQL_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_MSSQL_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_MSSQL_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_MSSQL_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_MSSQL_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

and this to my .env file

```
DB_MSSQL_HOST=
DB_MSSQL_PORT=
DB_MSSQL_DATABASE=
DB_MSSQL_USERNAME=
DB_MSSQL_PASSWORD=
```

But what is the next step? google didnt really help me that much, in laravel 4.* you could use db::connection(); but it dosent seem to work anymore

Any ideas?

Comment: Submitted an answer. Le the know if it works for you. Be sure to hit accept and/or vote up the answer if it was helpful for you. Otherwise you'll avoid having your questions answered in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to set-up one or more databases in your config (be sure to change values, I just pretty much copied and pasted):

```
'db1' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => env('DB_MSSQL_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_MSSQL_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_MSSQL_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_MSSQL_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_MSSQL_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],

'db2' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => env('DB_MSSQL_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_MSSQL_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_MSSQL_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_MSSQL_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_MSSQL_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

Then of course, you're going to need to create some migration schema for the newly added database (you need tables, etc.):

```
Schema::connection('db2')->create('table_name', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    ...
});
```

Now in your Eloquent model, you can define what database you want to use like so:

```
class ModelName extends Eloquent {

    protected $connection = 'db2';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Mike Barwick, the only thing that i was looking for was `protected $connection = ""`

Now i can query 2 databases at once

Comment: Hi, I am new in Laravel. And I have a case like yours which I have to get data from sqlsrv database, and the main database that I use is mysql. Should I change your `class DB extends Model {Protected $table = "mssql_table";}`  into `class ModelName extends Eloquent { protected $connection = 'db2';}` or I make a new model? And shoud I make schema::connection?

Comment: I did make a new connection as showed in the OT and added the $connection = "mssql"; in that particular MODEL. Regarding if you should use the Schema::connection, that is up to you on how you handle your DB structure.